# codecfix.exe virus and VLC Player and Windows 7

Tags: windows, virus, video

I downloaded a .wmv file (supposedly the new movie War Dogs) from thepiratebay.org, and when I tried to play it using VLC, a dialog box popped up, indicating some error. Information about this error kept on being written to this box so VLC was looping and I quit it by right-click -> quit.

The readme file associated with the .wmv file said to use windows media player, but here is where I got suspicious and shift+del both the readme file and the .wmv file. After some searching, I came across the following reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Piracy/comments/4g3b8f/psa_codecfixexe_virus_appearing_in_certain_video/

This led to me to these two stackexchange posts:
1. [Can a rogue .wmv file "hijack" Windows Media Player?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106188/can-a-rogue-wmv-file-hijack-windows-media-player)
2. [Is VLC on Linux vulnerable to an attack from .wmv files designed to install viruses?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122089/is-vlc-on-linux-vulnerable-to-an-attack-from-wmv-files-designed-to-install-viru)

Based on the reddit post and the readme file, I'm pretty sure that I downloaded the same malicious file as the guy from the first stackexchange post. So my question is: Is my computer infected?

Based on the second stackexchange post, the answer appears to be no, but that question was about VLC on Linux, while I am on Windows 7. My computer has been behaving completely normally, but I don't have an antivirus installed. However, I did do a quick scan using the Microsoft's August 2016  malicious software removal tool, and it couldn't find any infected files. Anyways, I'm still a bit worried so can anybody confirm that this virus doesn't work with VLC?

By the way, when I went back to the pirate bay to check out this torrent, it was gone, but now, there's another War Dogs torrent that has about 17000 seeders and 800 leechers; I suspect it's the same malicious file: hxxxs://thepiratebay.org/torrent/15555357/War_Dogs_2016_720p_BrRip_x264_-_SPARKS

Comment: The readme file tells you to use WMP to open the file, so there's a good chance the exploit only works against that player (otherwise why would they tell you to use it?). Since you didn't open it you are safe.

Comment: Micrisoft scanner won't detect such malware. It has very low detection ratio and I am not sure if it scans wmv files at all.

Comment: @Aria if the malware is the same as in the linked question them the video file does not contain it - it just contains an URL and hopes to social-engineer the user to make them install the "codecs" located at that URL. It's only once they try to download it that antimalware would (hopefully) catch the malicious .exe.

Comment: I'm not sure how we could possibly determine if your computer is infected. I'd assume that you are, and move forward from that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I run this myself and what it did it created some files:

- c:\users\me\Temp\LH4P238G44.exe
- c:\drive_c\users\me\Temp\1AI9XBO4U6\bureautique.exe
- c:\onespd\otutnetwork.exe and config.ini
- c:\Program Files (x86)\onespd

In config.ini there's `maji=tytyuaaua`

Here are the scans results:
https://virustotal.com/en/file/f67590816306117e88ef6c67c6f5d6d1453ddfa1460c4dab846b86184982dec9/analysis/1471121151/

https://virustotal.com/en/file/d129792d6afa7b2cf1bfb86f225822cb941c99e30ce264026963aaf56a3e2e93/analysis/1471121206/

https://virustotal.com/en/file/21c68d4b6914bc1e185c03c632d6f2eaf779ea9e8ebe4075a45015733edd41fe/analysis/1471121316/

https://virustotal.com/en/file/807878a330893176423d8567d8fe0a091d41c11f3fe410ad18a10cb93d349263/analysis/1471121259/

https://virustotal.com/en/file/7322c3fefd8c25de5df9c5d4251aa157632f80126b9adf5810999a268f9aa52b/analysis/1471121330/

You get free panda now and get rid of it ASAP.

Here is the scan of original file:

https://virustotal.com/en/file/c9c4c39a294cbf3b62fc11376101d2d78201da4da066509d67892b698d201720/analysis/1471121592/

Comment: I downloaded malwarebytes yesterday and ran a full scan; it only found some PUP files. I tried opening the .wmv file with VLC, not WMP, so I was never confronted with the prompt to download any malicious .exe. I also don't have any of the files mentioned above in my C:\ directory. I'll still download panda antivirus to see if it'll pick up anything malwarebytes missed. Thank you for your help!